# Can I recover my USDT sent to a USD/PAX?

Tags: cross-chain-recovery, lost-transactions, binance

HI I sent USDT from my binance account to usd/pax blockchain wallet how i can recover that funds please ?

Comment: If "usd/pax blockchain wallet" refers to a service provided by Paxful, you should probably reach out to Paxful's customer service. Voting to close as off-topic for customer service request.